# Funcionamiento de las migraciones en Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Necesito realizar una migración de ruby on rails en el servidor de producción pero en una carpeta de pruebas donde quiero volver a montar el proyecto para así tener una manera de hacer diferentes modificaciones para que no tenga ningún cambio el proyecto que esta en uso, entonces la pregunta en concreto es, si realizo un **rake db:migrate** en esta parte no afecto la base de datos de producción? aclaro! ya tengo una base de datos alterna para esta parte de las pruebas

Comment: `rake db:migrate` afectará la base de datos que tengas configurada en _config/database.yml_.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Para que pudieses afectar tu bd de producción, deberías ejecutar algo como `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate` e incluso así, si no tienes acceso desde tu máquina al servidor de producción (o al menos no deberías en un sistema bien configurado), difícil que pudieses hacer algún cambio.